# Safe to remove 'OpenFeint' folder?

Tags: gallery, delete

Given that OpenFeint seems to no longer be in service [(OpenFeint service shutting down Dec 14)](http://www.polygon.com/2012/11/16/3655496/openfeint-shutting-down-dec-14-could-disrupt-ios-android-games), was wondering if it is safe to remove the OpenFeint folder from the phone.

The main reason is that for some odd reason, OpenFeint images have been showing up in my Gallery, which is really annoying. I've stopped them from showing up by adding the '.nomedia' file in the directories. Whilst doing this, I thought - can't I just remove the entire directory given OpenFeint is no longer in service?

Does anyone know if it will cause any problems?

Answer (score 1):

I won't cause any problem and you can easily delete it.
To be dead sure you can try renaming the directory to something else and see if anything happens. But as I said it's perfectly ok to remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Openfeint is an app addon that tracks High Scores for the registered apps/games.

Removing it *might* remove your highscore records on your phone, reducing your bragging rights :P

But other than that, if you are not concerned deleting your scores, then you may remove it.

Comment: Didn't they give up anyway? It was a sucky system which never worked for me.  Whatever the apps which used it are now using is, it's much better.